# Definition and Etymology of "Diplasiology"

Tags: meaning, etymology, greek

Reading Benjamin Jowett's translation of the *Phaedrus* of Plato, I have come across the word **diplasiology**:

> And there is also Polus, who has schools of diplasiology, and gnomology, and eikonology, and who teaches in them the words of which Licymnius made him a present; they were to give a polish.

What does this word mean? What are its constituent Greek roots?

1. Am I correct in assuming that di- is the common binary prefix (from δίς)?
2. *Plasi-* is the stem I am completely ignorant of.
3. I know of course that -logy is from λόγος.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.scribd.com/doc/45920218/A-New-History-of-Classical-Rhetory),

> "Diplasiology” means “doubling” words; the Neoplatonic commentator Hermeias understood the term literally, as in “Alas, alas”; modern scholars tend to think words compounded of two roots are referred to.

Sorry I cannot help with the Greek roots, aside from pointing out that your guess on di- looks right, but maybe that definition will help point you to the right stem, too.

Answer (score 4):

This is to complement @JeffSahol's answer. Apparently *plasi-* is from **πλάσις**, a molding or formation, which is from **πλάσσω**, "I mold" or "I form"; this is also the root of *plastic* and *plasma*; see the Free Dictionary on [-plasia](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/-plasia), a suffix used in medical terms such as *dysplasia*.